# Why is the text blue at and after the form tags?

Tags: html, css

The following is the HTML file that is giving so much strife at the moment.
Head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Cheat Sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css ">
</head>
```

Body section:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>The wolves stopped in their tracks, sizing up the mother and her cubs. 
            It had been over a week since their last meal and they were getting desperate.
            The cubs would make a good meal, but there were high risks taking on the mother Grizzly. 
            A decision had to be made and the wrong choice could signal the end of the pack.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="box-2">
        <h1>Goodbye World</h1>
        <p>The red glow of tail lights indicates another long drive home from work after an even longer 24-hour shift at the hospital. 
            The shift hadn't been horrible but the constant stream of patients entering the ER meant there was no downtime. 
            She had some of the “regulars” in tonight with new ailments they were sure were going to kill them. 
            It's amazing what a couple of Tylenol and a physical exam from the doctor did to eliminate their pain, nausea, headache, 
            or whatever other mild symptoms they had. Sometimes she wondered if all they really needed was 
            some interaction with others and a bit of the individual attention they received from the nurses.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="categories">
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1</li>
            <li><a href="#2">Category 2</li>
            <li><a href="#3">Category 3</li>
            <li><a href="#4">Category 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

After this point, all the text appears blue on my chrome browser. Please help me figure out what's causing this

```
    <form class="my-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message: </label>
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="">
    </form>
    <div class="block">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>The red glow of tail lights indicating another long drive home from 
            work after an even longer 24-hour shift at the hospital. 
            The shift hadn't been horrible but the constant stream of patients 
            entering the ER meant there was no downtime.
        </p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- ./container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I am learning by myself via tutorials.

Comment: In `<li><a href="#">Category 1</li>` you have `<a>` but not `</a>`

Comment: yep as @qrsngky said it's all your ```li``` items too not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to close all the anchor tags `<li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>`

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

By default, a link will appear like this: An un-visited link is underlined and blue. A visited link is underlined and purple. An active link is underlined and red.

So as you are using anchor tag `<a href="#">` without closing it, the text is blue. Also it's best practice to close tags to avoid any security issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please close all the anchor Tag `<li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>`, Also please make sure that all the Tags are closed. [Click here](https://prnt.sc/kB1GIBP08jVi)